# jQuery datepicker specific dates per month (ie; 1st and 15th only)

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Firstly I can't find a solutions anywhere, I am creating a Direct Debit payment system and our provider will only let us use the 1st and 15th of each month and a minimum of 7 days from today (which I have done) but I am having trouble finding the solution to only let the user select 1st or 15th...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 3, showCurrentAtPos: 0,
            minDate: "+7d",
            maxDate: "+2m"
        });
    });     
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the "beforeShowDay" function to your datePicker as follow :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 3, showCurrentAtPos: 0,
                minDate: "+7d",
                maxDate: "+2m",
                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                  if (date.getDate() == 15 || date.getDate() == 1) {
                     return [true, ''];
                  }
                  return [false, ''];
                }
            });
        });     
 </script>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I actually fixed it myself and could be quite useful for others...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 3, showCurrentAtPos: 0,
            minDate: "+7d",
            maxDate: "+2m",
            beforeShowDay: available
        });

        function available(date) {
            var day = date.getDate(),
                last=(new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth() + 1, 0, 23, 59, 59)).getDate();
            if (day==1||day==15) {
                return [true, "", "Available"];
            } else {
                return [false, "", "unAvailable"];
            }
        }
    });             
</script>
```